# Maven multimodules, start tests from one module with dependency from another

Tags: maven

I have two maven modules with integartion tests:

```
parent|
      --ui
      --api
```

How to start ui tests if they need jar of api module, but without api tests.
In my mind it looks like:

```
-pl api package -DskipTests (AND) -am clean test -pl ui
```

Answer (score 0):

Find solution:
`mvn install -DskipTests=true -pl api` (use it in "pre step" in jenkins)
and after install

```
mvn clean test -pl ui
```